# How to get PtrInt from CWnd* ?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I need to get the PtrInt from parameter that i get in C++ / CLI code

the input is CWnd* and i need to return the PtrInt as output.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean IntPtr? You can create if from a native pointer using IntPtr(void*) constructor:

```
IntPtr ptr((void*)pWnd);
```